# how to use table layout with scroll view to draw only visible area

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-tablelayout

I have this problem of a tablelayout performance related issue. If I have a very long list then there is a noticeable lag when it try to draw all the rows.  I know that for listview/gridview I can take advantage of the adapter object so that only visible area will be drawn.

However I need to control the number of columns per row depending on the text within each cell. so for one row could have only 1 column but for another row there could have 5 columns, thus I cannot use listview/gridview as I understand they all only support fix number of columns per row.

So is there any way around this? or I am stuck with writing my own code to determine the area I need to draw/update, this is very tricky as scrolling is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can and you have to use ListView and have different layout for every item. See this link for more info:

[Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)